# What location for downloadable files in JBoss?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, deployment, jboss7.x

In my webapp, clicking on some menu opens a new window and displays a PDF file.
Currently, these PDF files are located in a folder at the same level as WEB-INF. (the path is stored in the database)
Problem is, if I ever want to modify one of those files, I'll have to re-generate my WAR file and re-deploy it.
In order to avoid this kind of dependency, is there any way to store my PDF files on the server, and if so, where ?
Also, what would the path look like ? (currently it's something like /documents/Blabla/blublu.pdf)

Thank you very much for any help !

Comment: A web application is not necessarily a war file. It may be a directory with .war suffix. Try deploying your site not as a war file but as a directory. In this case you may be able to place the files there while the server is running.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926408/how-do-i-configure-a-static-context-path-in-jboss7 this is not possible in JBoss7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the files somewhere else on the server and create a mapping to this directory in a server.xml. See here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExternalDirectories

Keep in mind, that the files will not be secure

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I've read the link you gave me but there no information about JBoss AS-7, it's my bad, I didn't mention the version of my JBoss.
Why won't the files be secure ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer jny provided is very generic and applicable to all versions of JBoss. JBoss uses Tomcat underneath as the web server.